# Error in from torch.utils.data import utils

Tags: python, python-3.7

Following is the code used with PyTorch 1.0.1

```
import torch
import torch.utils
import torch.multiprocessing as multiprocessing
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import SequentialSampler
from torch.utils.data import RandomSampler
from torch.utils.data import BatchSampler
from torch.utils.data import _utils
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _DataLoaderIter

from torch.utils.data._utils import collate
from torch.utils.data._utils import signal_handling
from torch.utils.data._utils import MP_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL
from torch.utils.data._utils import ExceptionWrapper
from torch.utils.data._utils import IS_WINDOWS
from torch.utils.data._utils.worker import ManagerWatchdog
```

Upon execution, I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-34f56ac3615b> in <module>()

         12 from torch.utils.data import RandomSampler
         13 from torch.utils.data import BatchSampler
    ---> 14 from torch.utils.data import _utils
         15 from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _DataLoaderIter
         16 

ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'torch.utils.data' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Can you update PyTorch? It seems that is the problem as mentioned here https://github.com/sanghyun-son/EDSR-PyTorch/issues/165

Comment: update does not work

Comment: update should work, what does it say when you print ```torch.__version__``` ?

Comment: Name: torch
    Version: 1.10.0+cu111
    Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/
    Author: PyTorch Team
    Author-email: packages@pytorch.org
    License: BSD-3
    Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
    Requires: typing-extensions
    Required-by: torchvision, torchtext, torchaudio, fastai

Comment: update does not work howsoever hard I try...tried installing different versions but the problem persists. Resolving one conflict leads to another

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the official documentation [torchdata.datapipes](https://pytorch.org/data/beta/index.html) could guide on solving these issues. Or in the worst, try to tun `pip list` to see all environments and packages altogether.